# Are the reactive programming tools like Project Rector, Vertx, RxJava substitute Akka Actor model?

Tags: akka, rx-java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, vert.x

For past couple of years I am seeing changes in "Reactive Programming/System" world. To implement Non-blocking, async, back pressure systems these are very good candidates. But often I try to see which one(s) is best among Akka/ProjectReactor/RxJava/Vertx to build reactive systems and also that can implement "Reactive Manifesto".

Personally I have used Akka at good level and have fair idea on Project-Reactor/Spring webflux. During my analysis ,I see that Akka satisfies all "Reactive Manifesto" properties , in fact is built on top of these principles. It provides several features like parallelism, inherent concurrency(Actor), Streams, APIs,Clusters, Monitoring, Resiliency ,...etc.

Other-side Project-Reactor like frameworks integrated/adopted well by Spring community,followed by Kafka Reactive, R2Drivers, R2Socket ....etc.

I think either of these alone not satisfying all requirements of reactive system. Seems we need combination like Akka and Reactor OR Akka & RxJava..... Please Share your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bit of an "opinion" question, but I'll try.
Akka is also a reactive framework. In fact, Akka and Vert.x are quite close in their concepts. They all "implement" [Reactive Manifesto](https://www.reactivemanifesto.org).

Let's see this on a Vert.x example:

> Responsive: The system responds in a timely manner if at all possible.

This basically says that slow requests shouldn't block faster requests.
Vert.x utilises MultiReactor design pattern to provide responsiveness. This pattern is based on multiple `EventLoop` threads that aim to execute functions in a queue as quickly as possible.

> Resilient: The system stays responsive in the face of failure.

This basically says that the system shouldn't crash altogether if a single request fails.
Vert.x uses the concept of Handlers to process new events. In case of an error, it will be handled by an ErrorHandler.

> Elastic: The system stays responsive under varying workload.

The unit of elasticity in Vert.x is a `Verticle`. We can add more verticles at runtime to process more requests, and we also can undeploy verticles.

> Message Driven: Reactive Systems rely on asynchronous message-passing
> to establish a boundary between components that ensures loose
> coupling.

Vert.x uses `EventBus` to pass messages between Verticles.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I understood that akka and vert.x follows similar path. I can also see high-level these two are similar.  I am thinking that , one way is, we can choose "Akka + other reactor libraries like R2Drivers, Netty, Reactor"  OR "Vert.x + Other reactor libraries like R2Drivers, Netty". So that either option allows to build end to end reactive system ( UI --> Middleware --> Applayer --> Database Integration.....etc).